# Travis CI does not export env valriables

Tags: travis-ci

I have a project [here](https://github.com/liferay/alloy-editor). This project I forked in my own [private repository](https://github.com/ipeychev/alloy-editor).
They both have absolutely the same .travis.yml files ([here](https://github.com/liferay/alloy-editor/blob/master/.travis.yml) and [here](https://github.com/ipeychev/alloy-editor/blob/master/.travis.yml)).

The problem is that when Travis runs the build process from my [private repository](https://travis-ci.org/ipeychev/alloy-editor/builds/48470561), it successfully exports the env variables. However, when it runs the build process from the [other repository](https://travis-ci.org/liferay/alloy-editor/builds/48473815), these variables are not being exported and build fails.

Does someone have an idea why?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The environment variables are encrypted, and the key that's used is specific per repository. So environment variables encrypted with the key for `liferoy/alloy-editor` won't be decryptable when used on the `ipeychev/alloy-editor` project.

You'll need to re-encrypt them if you want them to have as part of your build. As these are used for Sauce Labs, you'll likely have to set up your own account and encrypt your own credentials.

Comment: I see, I didn't know the key is specific per repository.